# Save model with data from form using Play with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to create and save a new **Supply** model with data from a `form`.

Here's the relevant code from **SuppliesController**:

```
  def submitSupplyOffer = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    SupplyForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      form => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.supplies.index(request.identity, form))),
      data => {
        val supply = Supply(
          id = UUID.randomUUID(),
          userID = request.identity.userID,
          resource = data.resource,
          amount = data.amount
        )
        for {
          supply <- supplyService.save(supply.copy())
          result <- Redirect(routes.Application.index())
        } yield {
          result
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

---

And here is the error I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect.apply` returns a `Result`, not a `Future[Result]`, so you need to pull it out of the for-comprehension:

```
  def submitSupplyOffer = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    SupplyForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      form => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.supplies.index(request.identity, form))),
      data => {
        val supply = Supply(
          id = UUID.randomUUID(),
          userID = request.identity.userID,
          resource = data.resource,
          amount = data.amount
        )
        for {
          supply <- supplyService.save(supply.copy())
        } yield Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested but now I get another error. The error I get is `Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.` I have further checked that this is probably because I am using a **SecuredAction**, right? But I can not use a simple **Action** since I need to pass the `request.identity` to **BadRequest**

Comment: That error is unrelated to Play and your action. You usually need an `ExecutionContext` when dealing with scala futures--see [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future). You can do as the error says and `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` (or inject an `ExecutionContext` if you're using Play's dependency injection)

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I have managed to solve the errors with what you told me, and also the remaining errors that appeared afterwards but were easy to solve! :)